# Not getting any response when using restoreCompletedTransactions()

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I have implemented in app purchases in my app. Buying is working fine, but I can't restore purchases.

When `restorepurchasenow`is pressed nothing happens, although I have implemented `SKPaymentTransactionState.Restored` case in the payment queue. I am using sandboxing users to test this, can it be the problem ?

Here is my code :

```
@IBAction func restorepurchasesnow(sender: AnyObject) {


if transactionInProgress {
    return
}

    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions()
    restorepurchase.setTitle(NSLocalizedString("settings.inprogress", comment: "Transaction in progress"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    self.transactionInProgress = true
    println("Trying to restore purchases") // I get this message


}

func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, updatedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!) {

    println("did receive answer from server") // this never gets fired


    for transaction in transactions as! [SKPaymentTransaction] {

        switch transaction.transactionState {

        case SKPaymentTransactionState.Purchased:
            println("Transaction completed successfully.")
            SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction)
            transactionInProgress = false
            removeads.setTitle(NSLocalizedString("settings.proenabled", comment: "Pro version purchased"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            didpurchaseremoveads()


        case SKPaymentTransactionState.Failed:
            println("Transaction Failed");
            SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction)
            transactionInProgress = false


        case SKPaymentTransactionState.Restored:
            let prodID = transaction.payment.productIdentifier as String
            println(prodID)
                if prodID == "removeads" {

                    println("Purchase restored")
                    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction)
                    removeads.setTitle(NSLocalizedString("settings.proenabled", comment: "Pro version purchased"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                    restorepurchase.setTitle(NSLocalizedString("settings.restore", comment: "Restore purchases"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                    transactionInProgress = false
                    didpurchaseremoveads()

                } else {

                    transactionInProgress = false
                    println("Puchase restaured but no compatible products were found")
                    restorepurchase.setTitle(NSLocalizedString("settings.restore", comment: "Restore purchases"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                }

        default:
            println(transaction.transactionState.rawValue)
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

I have implemented :

```
   func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!,
        restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError error: NSError!){

            println(error)
    }
```

And I get the following error : `Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" UserInfo=0x17427c840 {NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes Store}` What gives ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running this in the simulator? If so, I believe you can't fully complete a restore purchases that way. I think it had to be run on a device. Basically the simulator does not support StoreKit.